# Не работает Sub из главного Sub

Tags: vba

Всем привет,

Основная задача в том, чтобы из главной программы передать в дополнительную несколько переменных. Суть проблемы: программы выполняет 1 стоку и выходит из нее, продолжая выполнение основного алгоритма

Код:

```
Call HeatMapComlex(RobotName = RobotName, heat_map_start = HeatMapLastRow - 48, heat_map_end = HeatMapLastRow, amount_of_process = UBound(ProcessPerRobot, 2))
On Error Resume Next
```

2

```
Sub HeatMapComlex(RobotName As String, heat_map_start, heat_map_end, amount_of_process As Integer)

Dim header_columns, RobotCal, row_num, col_num, time_cell As Integer
Dim HeatMap(0 To 47) As Boolean


Worksheets(RobotName).Activate

For row_num = heat_map_start To heat_map_end
```

Из второй программы выходит сразу после выполнения Worksheets(RobotName).Activate

Comment: Сразу? И не пытается перейти к циклу? Возможно, начальное значение цикла больше конечного. Возможно, при активации ошибка, но где-то отключена обработка ошибок. Покажите пример === При вызове процедуры понаписывали много лишнего. Не нужно присваивать переменной другую переменную, процедура и без этого все поймет

Comment: Спасибо. Ошибка как раз была из-за присвоения аргументов. Передвались значения True, из-за этого дейтсвия завязанные на переменных прерывали процесс

Comment: И точно. А я об этом как-то не подумал. Это же булевы значения получались ;)